# Judge "it" for yourself

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, expressions, phrase-usage

#### Context

I'd like to ask a question in an email and I need to explain that I already speak two foreign languages fairly well. I don't want to seem overly confident as I know I still make mistakes, but I can keep a conversation going with anyone using these languages.

As the email I'm writing is quite long, I assume there could be one or two mistakes in it. I thought about adding the "judge it for yourself" phrase, but I'm not sure I'm using it correctly. A Google Search didn't show me relevant hits, so I'm even more inclined to suspect that the phrase might be a little off.

#### Question

> (... bla bla bla, I moved to Germany, but don't speak the language...)
>
> I already speak English and Spanish fairly well (well, judge it for yourself, though) and now I am learning German.
>
> (btw, is the double well awkward?)

Is this correct? Would you recommend me using another phrase?

PS. If I made any other mistakes in this post, let me know and feel free to point them out, because it's difficult for me to spot unidiomatic phrases.

Comment: Since the email is writing not speaking, I’d leave the whole “you can judge for yourself” clause out completely.

Comment: And if it was speaking? I'd like to know how to use this phrase (or find a better one). Thanks for the tip, I'll consider leaving it out from the email.

Answer (score 1):

The usual and customary phrase is "judge for yourself", without the "it". [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Judge%20for%20yourself%2C%20judge%20it%20for%20yourself&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CJudge%20for%20yourself%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjudge%20it%20for%20yourself%3B%2Cc0)
shows practically no incidence of "judge it for yourself" when compared to "judge for yourself".

And yes, I think the second "well" is awkward.